# Open code snippet from org-mode with C-' in a vertical split instead of an horizontal one

Tags: org-mode, window-splitting

In org-mode, I open a code snippet with C-' (org-edit-special) to edit it in a separate split. By default, it opens it in a horizontal split.

Is there a way to open a code snippet from org-mode with C-' in a vertical split?

Comment: Looks like someone (Eric) works on this to go into Org.  See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2019-07/msg00055.html

Comment: Thanks. I will keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the genuine Emacs' customization approach allows to do so:

`C-h v` ;; - to look at variable value by its name

```
org-src-window-setup ;; <---variable name
```

After that it is possible to choose any option from a broad list. Seems like *other-window* is what you're looking for.

Comment: I think `split-window-below` is the value that matches OPs request